# When materializing GlobalKTable from StateStore change-log topic and using exactly_once processing - other topic consumer stops working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka 2.4.1 and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR4

I am using a state-store for statefull processing and then using a GlobalKTable to materialize the state-store's changlog topic into a local store, so that interactive queries have access to the full dataset.

This works fine when using **at_least_once** processing guarantees - but when using **exactly_once** processing guarantees. Other consumers on *unrelated topics* stop working which seems very strange.

Also if I generate the data to an extra topic (so don't use the changelog topic) then everything is fine. So it really seems that there is some kind of interference when materializing a changelog topic into a GlobalStateStore.

Then on shutdown I get the following error
2020-05-12 19:08:46.468 ERROR 382785 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.processor.internals.StreamTask   : task [0_0] Could not close task due to the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot send offsets to transaction either because the producer is not in an active transaction
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.sendOffsetsToTransaction(TransactionManager.java:329)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:673)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:486)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.suspend(StreamTask.java:596)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.close(StreamTask.java:724)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.close(AssignedTasks.java:341)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.shutdown(TaskManager.java:267)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.completeShutdown(StreamThread.java:1230)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:800)
```

Is there any reason why this shouldn't work? Is my use-case considered invalid?

Thanks and sorry for not having an example

Comment: The error messages sounds like a bug in Kafka Streams. IIRC, it's fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out with a newer version and provide an update here